# Is the Yukawa potential the more accurate potential to describe nucleons nucleons interactions?

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, models, pions

According the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential)  the Yukawa  potential is of the form:
$$
V_{\text {Yukawa }}(r)=-g^{2} \frac{e^{-\alpha m r}}{r}
$$

I know that the best theory to describe nucleons nucleons interaction is quantum chromodynamics but as far as my knowledge goes its not practical to solve bound states problems.

Suppose that we want to solve the bound state solution of the Schrodinger equation or Dirac equation for example  for the Helium nucleus, is the Yukawa potential the more accurate potential that we have?

Comment: More accurate than what ?

Comment: @StephenG  more accurate than others potential which I do not know

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: If you want a specific alternative to improve your question, you could try [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woods%E2%80%93Saxon_potential).

Comment: Another option is the [Reid potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force#History).

Comment: There are a variety of simple (and more complex) model potentials which have been applied to nuclei.  You could also mean the Coulomb potential as a basis of comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most accurate "potential" is the QCD Lagrangian, for which solutions are totally intractable. There are myriad nucleon-nucleon potentials, 3-nucleon, and even 4 nucleon potentials. The latter two describe forces that cannot be expressed as any combination of two-point interactions.

The gold standard is the Argonne V-18 potential (https://www.phy.anl.gov/theory/research/av18/). The name refers to both its origins (Argonne National Lab) and the fact that it has 18 kinds of terms, some of which are Yukawa-like. Its many free parameters are constrained by all sorts of experimental data, including scattering data (unbound states), and the structure of various bound states.

The Yukawa potential is the general form for what, in perturbation theory, is called "the exchange of a massive ($m$) boson". It can be expressed in both configuration space (${\bf r}$) and momentum space (${\bf q}$, with $\hbar=c=\alpha=1$:

$$V(r) = -g^2\frac{e^{-mr}} r $$

$$\tilde V(q) = -g^2\frac{4\pi} {q^2+m^2} $$

The original Yukawa potential referred to pion exchange ($m_{\pi}\approx 140\,$MeV/c), which gave an effective range of:

$$ R=\frac{\hbar c}{m_{\pi}c^2}
=\frac{197\,{\rm Mev\cdot fm}}{140\,{\rm MeV/c^2}c^2}=1.4\,{\rm fm} $$

which is indeed the range of attractive nuclear forces. Note that as $m\rightarrow 0$, $R\rightarrow \infty$ so that the Coulomb potential (photon exchange) is recovered with $g^2=e^2/4\pi\epsilon_0$:

$$V(r) \rightarrow \frac {-e^2} r$$

For the nuclear interaction,
additional repulsive terms attributed to other mesons that vary from "hard-core" to "soft-core" are required to fit data, though.

Moreover, the pion is a pseudo-scalar iso-vector meson, so the interaction term requires various factors to match that. Typical each has a configuration/momentum space potential ($V(r^2,p^2,L^2)$ and an iso-spin space term ($W(r^2, p^2,L^2)$) which is modified by an isoscalar operator $\tau_1\cdot \tau_2$.

Hence there is a central force:

$$V_C+\tau_1\cdot \tau_2W_C$$

A spin-spin interaction:

$$[V_S+\tau_1\cdot \tau_2W_S]\vec{\sigma}_1\cdot\vec{\sigma}_2$$

A spin-orbit term:

$$[V_{LS}+\tau_1\cdot \tau_2W_{LS}]\vec L\cdot(\vec{\sigma}_1+\vec{\sigma}_2)$$

A non-central tensor force:

$$[V_T+\tau_1\cdot \tau_2W_T](3(\vec{\sigma}_1\cdot\hat r)(\vec{\sigma_2}\cdot\hat r)-\vec{\sigma}_1\cdot\vec{\sigma_2})$$

A sigma-L term:

$$ [V_{\sigma L}+\tau_1\cdot \tau_2W_{\sigma L}]\frac 1 2 \big[
(\vec{\sigma_1}\cdot\vec L)(\vec{\sigma_2}\cdot\vec L)+
(\vec{\sigma_2}\cdot\vec L)(\vec{\sigma_1}\cdot\vec L)
\big]$$

and a sigma-p term:

$$[V_{\sigma p}+\tau_1\cdot \tau_2W_{\sigma p}]
(\vec{\sigma_1}\cdot\vec p)(\vec{\sigma_2}\cdot\vec p)$$

In addition to the $J^PI=0^-1$ pion, significant mesons are the:

1. $0^+0$ sigma
2. $1^-0$ omega
3. $1^-1$ rho

With that, the nucleon-nucleon interaction is complicated, and just can't make statements like "Yukawa is best".

Answer (score 1):

When used for describing nucleon-nucleon interactions, Yukawa potential plays the same role as the electrostatic potential plays for interacting charges - i.e., low-frequency limit of the actual interaction. Indeed, while the interaction between the charged particles is mediated by massless photons, described by the wave equation, the strong force is mediated by massive mesons, described by Klein-Gordon equation. The latter is a wave equation with a mass term, which is where the exponent in the Yukawa potential comes from.